# JS Count the number of elements with the same class from other page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find a solution to put a number of elements with the particular class that are on my other page. Is it possible to pass this data from one page to another only by us using JS? 
Can I solve it without implanting any code on the second page?

Page 1 (will include divs)

```
<div class"toy"></div>
<div class"toy"></div>
<div class"toy"></div>
<div class"toy"></div>
<div class"toy"></div>
```

Page 2 ( Here the number should be the result of counting divs with the class "toy" from page 1).

Ther are **5** Toys waiting for you.

Comment: getting the count may be impossible if the element is not in the DOM

Comment: The second page need to be able to fetch that data somehow, so some code need to be written and executed.

Comment: You can append a query string from page 1 when you navigate to page 2 containing the count of toys, however on both pages you'll need to include a little bit of code.

Comment: instead of counting the elements from the `html` page store the values to database (as `cart`) and then get the count of them on the next page.

Comment: you can use `ajax` to get content of page1 in page2 then can use `CONTENT.match(YOUR_CLASS_REGEX).length`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `http://example.com/page1.html` is an address of the first page from your example. Here is a JS code which counts the number of elements by loading the page 1 and parsing it:

```
function onCount(count) {
    if (typeof count === 'number') {
        alert('There are ' + count + ' Toys waiting for you');
    } else {
        alert('An error has happened');
    }
}

function ajaxGet(url, onload, onerror) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            onload(request.responseText);
        } else {
            onerror();
        }
    };
    request.onerror = onerror;
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send();
}

ajaxGet('http://example.com/page1.html', function (response) {
    var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, 'text/html');
    onCount(dom.querySelectorAll('.toy').length); // '.toy' is a CSS selector of an element you need to count
}, function () {
    onCount(false);
});
```

You should add this code to the JavaScript code of the second page.